# Can glow on the touch point when touch the view in IOS?

Tags: ios, touch

Just like the title ,when I touch the UIView I want the touch point to be glow, I came up with a idea that to show a glow image on the touch point ，but if by code？any example or idea？thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try touchesBegan event below Code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   if([touch view] ==self.my_view)//Check click your uiview or not
  {
       CGRect frame = [your_image_view frame];
       CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
       frame.origin.x=touchLocation.x;
       frame.origin.y=touchLocation.y;
       [your_image_view setFrame:frame];
       [self.my_view addSubview:your_image_view];
  }

}
```

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

Well the first step would be to detect the touch on your UIView for that I would recommend using the high level API [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) andd add to your view. Then you can use the call back to do whatever you want, perhaps some sort of animation?. If so you can use an animation block to animate your changes.